# Open directory windows with "Go to URL" in SSRS 2017

Tags: url, reporting-services, hyperlink, directory, subdirectory

it is possible open a directory with "Go to URL" in SSRS 2017?
Im try this:

[Image with im trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETn1.png)

field link have this information: "File://///192.168.1.2/Documentos/EMP/PV/"

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

Ensure your formatting for the filed that holds the directory information like this :

> \\192.168.1.2\documentos\EMP\PV\